# If $f$ is analytic in $\Omega\subset\mathbb{C}$, then why is $f$ bounded in a neighbourhood of $z_0 \in \Omega$?

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-functions, analyticity

The notion of analyticity I am working with is that a complex function $f:\Omega\subset\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$ is analytic in $\Omega$ if for any $z_0 \in \Omega$ $f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n(z - z_0)^n, a_n \in \mathbb{C}$ for $z$ in some neighbourhood of $z_0$ where the said powerseries is convergent.

My question is is that how do we know that an analytic function is bounded in this neighbourhood of $z_0$? Let $B(z_0, r)$ be the aforementioned neighbourhood of $z_0$. Then, we know immediately from the definition of analyticity and convergence of infinite series that $\forall z \in B(z_0, r):\exists M_z \in \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}:|f(z)|\leq M_z < \infty$, as the series representation of $f$ would not converge otherwise. But if were to take supremum of $|f(z)|$ over all $z$ in $B(z_0, r)$, what would stop the local bound of $f$ from growing without a bound, i.e. that $\sup_{z\in B(z_0, r)}|f(z)| = \infty$?

Comment: Weierstrass Theorem: a continuous function on a compact domain (in $\;\Bbb R^n\;,\;\;\Bbb C^n\;$) is bounded there.

Comment: @DonAntonio Ah, so we extend the neighbourhood of $z_0$ to contain its boundary? But could there be a pathological example in which the boundary of $z_0$'s neighbourhood cannot be included?

Comment: The function's bounded in SOME (closed, to be sure) neighborhood of the point, not precisely in the one obtained by its power series as Steven's answer explains.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We do not know that.

For example, $\frac{1}{1-z} = \sum_0^\infty z^n$ is not bounded on the disk of convergence $|z|<1$.

You can say that if you shrink the domain slightly to a compact subset of the disk of convergence (in my example, say, $|z|\leq 1 - \epsilon$) then $f$ will be bounded in modulus on this restricted domain simply because it is a continuous function on a compact set.